# R: grouping character values and leave only one value from the vector by condition

Tags: r, data.table, character, aggregate, grouping

For example, I have the following dataset (my real dataset has more than 100000 rows and 70 variables):

```
Country   Year   Flag
Norway    2018   drop: reason1
Norway    2018   drop: reason2
Sweden    2016   drop: reason3
France    2011   drop: reason2
France    2011   drop: reason3
France    2011   drop: reason4
```

Firstly, I want to group **Flag values** by variables **Country** and **Year**, so I want to get a table like this:

```
Country   Year   Flag
Norway    2018   drop: reason1, drop: reason2
Sweden    2016   drop: reason3
France    2011   drop: reason2, drop: reason3, drop: reason4
```

Secondly, if there are more than one value in the Flag column, I want to leave only 1 with the following logic: 
if the `drop: reason1` is present, then leave it and remove the rest. If there is no `drop: reason1`, but there is a `drop: reason2` and a `drop: reason3`, then we leave only the `drop: reason2`.

Finally, my dataset should look like this:

```
Country   Year   Flag
Norway    2018   drop: reason1
Sweden    2016   drop: reason3
France    2011   drop: reason2
```

I would like to implement this based on the data.table or base R approach.

I would be very grateful for any help!
At least for the first part of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can `order` the data by `Country` and `Flag` and then select the 1st value of `Flag` for each `Country` and `Year`.

This can be done in base R:

```
aggregate(Flag~Country+Year, df[with(df, order(Country, Flag)), ], head, 1)

#  Country Year         Flag
#1  France 2011 drop:reason2
#2  Sweden 2016 drop:reason3
#3  Norway 2018 drop:reason1
```

Or `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  arrange(Country, Flag) %>%
  group_by(Country, Year) %>%
  summarise(Flag = first(Flag))
```

and with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[order(Country, Flag), (Flag = first(Flag)), .(Country, Year)]
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Country = structure(c(2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L),
.Label = c("France","Norway", "Sweden"), class = "factor"), Year = c(2018L, 2018L, 
2016L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L), Flag = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 4L), .Label = c("drop:reason1", "drop:reason2", "drop:reason3", 
"drop:reason4"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! And how can I get the first table from my question (with **all** possible unique variants for the flag value)? Sorry I'm new in R :((

Comment: @Hilary you could do `aggregate(Flag~Country+Year, df, function(x) toString(unique(x)))`